# How to grant permission Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS android 6.0

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to grant the permission `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`, but when I run the app, the dialog of the permission should appear but it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
int hasCameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MemoryDetail.this, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS);
if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MemoryDetail.this, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS)) {
        showDialogMessage("Need use permission: MANAGE_DOCUMENTS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS}, Database.PICK_PICTURE);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS}, Database.PICK_PICTURE);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you can perform a task that requires that permission? If you already have the permission then no dialog will appear.

Comment: I had declared permission in Manifest. If I use another permission, such as: CAMERA, CONTACTS... It work very well. If I don't use this permission, the error appear: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{87433d2 4941:com.devil.tetmemory/u0a86} (pid=4941, uid=10086) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS.

Answer (score 11):

`MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` is a `signature`-level permission. Ordinary Android apps cannot hold it. Only apps that were signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware can hold it.

Comment: Can you give me more detail information and tell me how I can solve this error. Thanks.

Comment: @mytruong: You "solve this error" by removing the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission from your manifest and Java code. You cannot have that permission.

Comment: I use Facebook API to share article from my app. When I run the app, it has this error, so I add this permission in Manifest and java code. If I run with android under version 6.0, such as: 5.0, 4.4... it works very well. I had done the same your help, but it doesn't still work @CommensWare.