# cordova unable to open fileURL returned by camera plugin after application restarted

Tags: android, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins, whitelist

I am using cordova version 7.0.1 and the cordova-plugin-camera version 2.4.1.
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFunction, failureFunction,options)
In the options, I use

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
```

I am getting the image URI correctly.
I create a "img" element and set the img.src to the URI returned by the plugin
The picture appears correctly.
Now, I store this URI in the application's local folder, and close the application.
I restart the application, and read the imageURI from storage.
Then, I create an "img" element and set the img.src to the URI read form storage.

The URI read from storage is identical to the URI earlier returned by the camera plugin getPicture() call.
But, the image file is not read and the picture does not appear on screen. The errors I am seeing are
Unable to open content URL:

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3237
>   URL blocked by whitelist: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3184

So, I thought this was a whitelist problem. I added 
    
into the config.xml file. But this makes the app crash when it tries to read the image file.

I am trying this on a Karbonn phone running Android Marshmallow.

Please do share the solution if you know what is wrong with the above, what else I need to do here.

Comment: While using Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI the camera store images in the cache-folder with android and in tmp-folder with ios by default. As far as I know the tmp (temporarily)-folder with ios is cleared sometimes and especially after restarting, So with android there can be a similar problem. Have yout tried to move an image into your app-folder (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE_H‌​ERE) and read it there after restarting?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Blauharley. But - I think this is not the cause for the problem I am having. I am not taking a new picture with the camera (sourceType:camera). I am using the plugin to fetch an image from the photolibrary (sourceType:photolibrary). And I am able to see that the filename (URI) is not a "cache" but in the phone's "content" folder.

Comment: Ok, excuse me......I've also had a similar problem and solved it by making a request to a certain folder (window.requestFileSystem) before an file could be saved there. Have you already tried that before creating an img element?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, this also is not the issue. I am not trying to save a file. The file is already existing in the gallery of the smartphone. The PHOTOLIBRARY option of the camera plugin simply returns a FILE_URI for the image file already available. When the FILE_URI is returned by the plugin, I am able to see the image on the screen. My problem is - when I save this same URI and use it again after restarting the application, the image does not show up on the screen. In both situations, I do not open the file myself. I just set img.src = FILE_URI i the javascript.

Comment: Nevertheless there might be a permission restriction, when you access an image via a camera you explicitly grants read/write-permssion onto a gallery-folder but just starting a app and accessing to this folder without the camera might not work, as it is obviously. Have your tried window.requestFileSystem?

Comment: Yes, I did try using window.requestFileSystem() and then using the same earlier imageURI to get a fileentry. using fs.root.getFile() passing imageURI as the 1st argument like - fs.root.getFile(imgUri, {create:false},
                function(fileEntry) {console.log("successful getting fileentry got image");}, 
                function() {console.log("Error - unable to get file entry for image");}
            );
The call fails and goes to the error function i.e. it is unable to get a fileentry.

Comment: Ok, strange thing. The last suggestion I can give is to move the image from the gallery to your app-folder and fetch it from there.

Comment: Another observation - I do see a message - 09-21 03:15:23.765 1184-1991/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{56c596e 5017:com.adsengg.skinsight/u0a118} (pid=5017, uid=10118) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
 - which seems to indicate this is a permissions problem. That is why, initially I had tried adding to the whitelist but unsuccessfully - I dont know what is the syntax to specifically add permission to the photo gallery folder in the whitelist

Comment: Very interesting! It seems on the first glance that there is no way to define this permission in your manifest, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35777269) says. Moving this gallery-image into the app-folder seem inevitable.

Comment: I tried using fileEntry.copyTo() method to move the image file into the app's folder. Below is my code for this

Comment: function makeCopy(fileentry) {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024,
        function(fs) {
            fileentry.copyTo(fs.root, fileentry.name,
                             function() {console.log("file copy success");},
                             function(e) {
                                 console.log("file copy fail - " + e.code);
                             });
        }, 
        function() {console.log('error opening filesystem');}
    );
}
The copyTo function fails and the callback code indicates ENCODING_ERR

Comment: Please make another question to solve this issue, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems when accessing an image from a "media-store" like the gallery without using "a certain system-app" like the camera, an ordinary app must hold the permission `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` in order to have access to that image.

**Unfortunately ordinary apps do not have this permission**, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35777269/2401386) says. Therefore a gallery-image must be moved/copied into the app-folder (`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/APP_NAMESPACE`) by using "a system-app" that holds the `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`-permission so that an ordinary app can show this image after a it was restarted for instance.

Answer (score 0):

FILE_URI returns base64 format and not a url. In order to save the image in a specific directory in the phone you need to use DATA_URL instead of FILE_URI